# how to display 3D bulidings with texture in Cesium?

Tags: web, 3d, gis, cesiumjs, czml

I'm working on 3D web-GIS of an urban area. 3D buildings (with texture)  were created in Arcgis and I'm looking for the best solution to display this 3D model on the web. I tried Cesium but I couldn't convert the KML file to CZML. What should I do to convert KML to CZML? Is there any other solution to display 3D buildins on the Web

Answer (score 3):

You could use the gltf format, which basically is JSON.
A converter script can be found on the [gltf github page](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF). Also you can convert files online on the cesium webpage.

Cesium provides a function to load gltf files named "Model.fromGltf" as described in their documentation.

Three.js offers the possibility to render gltf as well. You can find an example on the gltf github page as well.

Comment: Here is a Tutorial on how to load 3D models with cesium [link](https://cesiumjs.org/2014/03/03/Cesium-3D-Models-Tutorial/)